# ListView being drawn twice

Tags: android, android-listview

So I am rather confused right now. I am using an XML layout so I can show an empty view like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/samples_empty"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you have probably seen a billion times here on so.

So I do setContentView(R.layout.foo) and it works the first time, but if I return to this Activity (As in onPause has been called and then onResume) I get this:

[image]

I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the adapter and that works fine, what I don't get is why its being drawn twice?

Its not like I am creating a new ListView and then adding it to the view, I'm sure I would know about it if I was.

The `getView` method of the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RecordView av;
    if(convertView == null){
        av = new RecordView(mCtx, this, mRecords[position], position);
    }else{
        av = (RecordView) convertView;
        av.setRecord(mRecords[position]);
    }
    return av;
}
```

This would be what it would look like normally...

[image]

**NOTE**

This doesn't seem to be happening every single time, and doesn't happen on a single event happening, but when it does, its when I return from another screen.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when I had another activity on top (something that was transparent, like facebook chat heads, then I could see that the problem had occurred then, It doesn't seem to happen on onResume, but more likely on onPause which I actually don't do anything in.

Comment: Added. Anything else which would be informational?

Comment: Oh bam bam. I think I know. I might be inflating the view twice D:

Comment: Oh nope I call `this.removeAllViews();`

Comment: Where you call it and why? pls put this code here

Comment: In `onResume` as the data would have changed on the other screen.

Comment: Nope, I am just restarting the activity when the user returns until I can find a solution.

Comment: You can test whether using the convertView is really the cause of the problem (I think it is) by changing `getView` so that it *always* returns a new RecordView. I think you'll see the problem disappear. But even if it does, you should revert `getView` to its current definition, and then figure out what's going on in `RecordView.setRecord`. (And since RecordView is apparently a custom class, you should post the code for it here.)

Comment: RecordView is a rather large class. I will have a look into it when I get home later tomorrow.

Comment: a little performance tip never set the `width/height` of `ListView` to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because you are dynamically create the row view each time while the convertview still has the old view existing and it is being reused. To get around this problem, you should give an id to every view (that is, every child view in your `RecordView`)when you dynamically create them, for example a child textview in your `RecordView` class should be instantiated like this

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this.getContext());
tv.setId(1);
    ...
```

Then, in your getView:

```
if(convertView == null){
    av = new RecordView(mCtx, this, mRecords[position], position);
}else{
    av = (RecordView) convertView;
    av.findViewById(1).setText(mRecords[position]);
}
```

assuming your `mRecords` holds an array of String. If you have variant layout for different rows, you can provide a [type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) to each view. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row) for further details.

Comment: I am doing something rather similar to this if you check my post, I have a method that updates all the views.

Comment: Not at home sorry, thats where my code is, however it consists of just setting text fields and changing the colour of that bar depending on different things.

Comment: The only time the layout is inflated is when the view is created

Comment: I would suggest you to use convertView directly instead of casting to RecordView. By passing the view as parameter to an independent function like `setRecord(convertView)` you should be able to achieve the same purpose. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Okie tokies, I shall try it out.

Answer (score 1):

try changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of listview to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the app before you return to it. Like when it works as expected

Comment: this is not a matter of height here. The layouts are probably inflated twice from your adapter. Check to see that you import your layouts once properly and enable recycling.